# iOS Google Maps in directions to?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, routes, directions

How to do the directions in iOS Google Maps as follows?

[image]

Best Regards.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: refer to the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/7957736/864850

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps provides a [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) that you can call to get a sequence of directions between two locations.  That would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want the direction between   two place   for  that

you need to his an Google Direction API

*`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false&mode=driving",getPickUpCoordinate.latitude ,getPickUpCoordinate.longitude, center.latitude, center.longitude]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *responseData =  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (!error) {
        NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];`*